# How do I keep socket.on alive for only 'x' amount of inputs?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am creating a game where I take input from users and then once all the users have given an input, it displays all the inputs on the screen.

I want to keep the socket.on only alive till all the players have entered an input.

```
io.on("connection", function (socket) {
  console.log("connection established with", socket.id);
  var noOfPlayers = 2;

      socket.on("answer", function (data) {
    ANSWERS.push(data);
    console.log(ANSWERS);
  });
});
```

Comment: The `socket` in your code is not a single one, it's the current player's. So you can simply close it after the answer was received: `socket.disconnect(true);`

Comment: @ChrisG I added a socket.disconnect(true) under an if statement, but more clients seem to be connecting and are able to send data to the function

Comment: Can you put the code you've tried into the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

socket object refers to one client,

you can use `socket.once("answer",...` to close the listener after one call(per client), 
that way you will only get one answer from each client.

and in the listener function, you can check if `ANSWERS.length == noOfPlayers` to know if that client was the last one to answer